# keep full screen while opening a new native app

Tags: java, windows, macos, javafx

Scenario: 
1. My JavaFX desktop app is running full screen.
2. Through it, I ask the operating system to open a new file (.doc, .ppt, .avi etc.) with the default app used for that type.
3. I want to keep the Java/JavaFX app in full screen while the new file is opened by another file (Word etc).

Problem: my app goes out of full screen when I try to do this, but that's exactly what I don't want. I want to keep my app in full screen and the other program that opens the file to be shown over my app, while I'm still in full screen.

Does anyone have any ideas how this could be implemented and if it's possible? I'm looking for solutions for both Windows and OSX.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict your application not to go out of full screen by

```
primaryStage.fullScreenProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                if (!ov.getValue()) {
                    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave a test app to my customer to check. I'll come back with feedback.

Comment: Feedback: using what you have recommended doesn't keep full screen when I open another file with its default program (let's suppose I open a word doc from my Java program, which launches Word). Moreover, the toolbar is also shown when the new app launches, exactly as the behavior I had before.
Using this listener doesn't allow the user to get out of it by pressing ESC, which is a pain for non technical persons.

Comment: When you make your one window in full screen mode and you open another, it will remain in full screen mode but goes to back. (Try this with any other application eg. Chrome, Firefox). Even if you press Alt+Tab (which switch the screens) your full screened window will go to back and you can see the task bar. I guess you can not restrict this. Second, if you want to let the user switch back to normal screen, you may check for conditions like pressing ESC button and allow one.

Comment: Yep, you're right. It seems that there's no way in which I can accomplish this. I was looking for some time, but I didn't find a solution neither. Thanks for your input. Have a nice day!